# Cycles render creates artifacts on my images

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, image

[image: cycles render with 128 samples]

Hi, as you can see above, if you look carefully at the grass, when rendering the border of the image is clearly visible. You can also see vertical lines that sometimes appear on the grass. This really bothers me because if i want to get a close shot it is VERY pronounced. Mist is turned off, and so is ambient occlusion. I checked, that doesn't make a difference. I would also like to point out that i tried many node configurations for the material, and the texture has a perfect alpha background.